# trailing emails

Tags: email

Sometimes, I see the expression of "trailing emails" in business emails. I understand it means all previous emails between correspondents hanging from the most recent email.
Is the "trailing emails" accepted terms by native speakers? How about "threaded emails"? Both are accepted and used by native speakers?

Comment: *Email trail* sounds better to my ear than *trailing emails* when referring to the set of related correspondence. The *trail* is the set of email; the *thread* is the more conceptual *topic* that the *trail* is about, but there is considerable overlap between the terms.